# Is there a way to get a list of every person who's checked into a repository and have it all listed in on sha256 string?

Tags: string, git, list, sha256

Trying to have a code that will return a list of all the users who've checked into a GIT repo and output into one sha256 string. Is that possible?

Comment: How do you want to turn the users into sha hashes?

Comment: Yes, you could walk all the commits to find the commiter and/or author for each commit. I'm not sure what you mean by "returning one sha256 string".

Comment: I was just told to make a list of all users who access the repo and have it returned as one sha256 string. I am not quite familiar with the term to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ git shortlog -es --all; git shortlog -ces --all; } | cut -f2- | sort -u | sha256sum
```

`git shortlog -es` lists the number of commits per author; `git shortlog -ces` per committer. The lists are combined,  the first column (the number of commits) removed and the list is sorted.

Comment: Had to use shasum -a 256 on Mac but this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Finding the list of users is relatively straightforward. Here's a shell oneliner I just used:

```
git log | grep ^Author | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | sort | uniq
```

Adding `| sha256sum` to that gives a hash of that list.

You can modify the arguments to `cut` if you want to hash just the names or just the email addresses or what have you.